# trying to create a c++ dll in visual studio but no dll file after successful build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

hi
I have a pretty basic c++ project to compile, and I get 'build succeeded' but don't see a .dll file in the debug or release directories.

there are 4 object files, 2 manifest files, 1 idb, 1 dep, a vc90 debug database, a compiled resource script myprogram.dll.embed.manifest and a build log but no .dll

project properties configuration type is set to .dll

any ideas why there is no dll file?

thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a separate solution directory, the DLL is under that directory\debug (or release).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the .dll files are being compiled somewhere else, look at Project Properties (right click the project and select Properties). Select the Compile tab and see where the output is.